# Can 'reword' and 'rephrase' be used interchangeably?

Tags: difference

As this [website](https://explainqn.com/rephrase-vs-reword/) says,

> “rephrase” is to say or write something with different wording and “reword” is to change the wording of.

Isn't to *say or write something with different wording* the same as *to change the wording*?

[Hinative](https://hinative.com/questions/13267227) adds that rephrase

> means to say the same phrase but differently, often for clarification.

But isn't clarification also the goal of reword? If it's not for clarification, who would ever bother to reword.

Can 'reword' and 'rephrase' be used interchangeably? If not always, please give some examples.

Comment: Can you edit to give us details about what research you have already done so we do not end up telling you things you already know?

Comment: You might reword for lots of reasons: a signwriter might do it to fit a message on a sign; a poet might reword to get a rhyme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They don't have the same meaning. As Merriam-Webster points out, "[reword](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reword)" is the simple act of changing the words without changing the meaning:

> **2 :** to alter the wording of
> also : to restate in other words

It has nothing to do with improving the wording or adding clarity. Writers spend a lot of time rewording their writing. Sometimes it's to make things clearer, but other times it's to make things feel less cliché, or more authentic, to evoke a certain feeling in the reader, or even to make the writing *less clear* on purpose.

"[Rephrase](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rephrase)", however, almost always carries the meaning of making something easier to understand:

> **:** to phrase or express (something) in a different way especially to make the meaning clearer
> *Let me rephrase the question.
>
> … spoke first in precise medical terms, then quickly rephrased them in laymen's language.*

The second example above is especially clear that the intent of rephrasing is to make something clearer.

Comment: *"reword" is the simple act of changing the words without changing the meaning*: According to your own explanation, *rephrase* doesn't change the meaning either, it clarifies it. So it seems the difference is: *Reword* means using different words to express something which is already clear, *rephrase* means using different words or another structure to clarify something which is currently difficult to understand.

Comment: @mins Very close. I'd only remove "*which is already clear*". The "something" may be clear already, or not. It may be clearer after the rewording, or less clear, or neither. Clarity isn't part of the meaning of "reword" at all.

Answer (score 0):

**Rewording** is the process of substituting synonyms for words in text.

**Rephrasing** involves changing the order of the words in the text.

[Source](https://www.ref-n-write.com/blog/paraphrasing-techniques-for-rephrasing-rewording-and-rewriting/#:%7E:text=Rewording%20is%20a%20simple%20process,words%20in%20your%20essay%20paper.)

Comment: Neither of those seems right to me. Do you have a source?

Comment: That source isn't a reputable source. It disagrees with all the reputable dictionaries I've looked in, and has grammar mistakes like, "*...the user has just **taking** the idea from the original text...*"

Comment: How about this one? https://thecontentauthority.com/blog/reword-vs-rephrase  There are a million sources with this definition. Are all of them wrong?

Comment: If a million random sources disagree with four reputable ones, then yes, they're all wrong. If you can find a reputable source to back your claim, then that'll be significant, so please edit your answer to say which one and ping me in the comments.